# How to update AjaxControlToolkit to use the latest version of JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

As a result of some recent penetration testing I have been updating some of our code to use the latest version of JQuery (3.6.4). We have scheduled another round of testing, but in the meantime my colleague has been using the same tool the penetration tester uses to make sure we haven't missed anything. This tool has found a reference to JQuery I missed. It took me a while to find it, but it seems AjaxControlToolkit is generating a file called

> *TSM_CombinedScripts*=True&v=2GFwlGU9ATlFIxrdsXRzcja58_1t5F8HSleaZM4ZQwk1&*TSM_Bundles*=&cdn=false

which contains JQuery 1.9.1.

My question then, is how do I get AjaxControlToolkit to use the latest version of JQuery - or just not to include version 1.9.1 in the above file? The latest version of JQuery is already on the page so it shouldn't need to include the old version. I've tried adding an AjaxControlToolkit.config, with a remove clause to stop it using the old version but that made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, you conclusion looks to be correct.

Looking at aj toolkit, and searching for jQuery, I see/find this:

[image]

And the problem is that when the aj toolkit is built, then the scripts are included in "resource" files, so they can be used by the various bits and parts.

I think the build I am using is 19.1, or 20.

Regardless, since I done some customizing of the aj toolkit, then I don't use the latest version.

You could check/download/try/look at the latest version of the aj kit and see what version of jQuery it uses.

You MIGHT be able to remove the jQuery reference in aj toolkit and assume (like you stated) that jQuery is already available.

I've not done this, but as a first step, I would thus suggest you consider taking the aj toolkit source code and re-building it.

It is a monster bit of code and inter-related libraries.

I was using aj dialogs, and I am still using the HTML editor, and the ajaxfile-download.

I now use jQuery.UI dialogs in place of the aj one.

So, only 2 parts I use are: AjaxFileDownload, and HTML editor.

Anyway, I did not realize that jQuery was included, and thus as a first step, I will update that jQuery library.

However, (unfortunately), I have not tested if I can remove it all together. My first choice would be to remove the jQuery reference, but I suspect this will mess up the building of the project. As I noted, the scripts are included in the DLLs as resource files, so it not going to be "oh so simple" to remove the scripts.

VERY important:

You need to get/grab/adopt/have a .js minimizer for your project. When I modify any .js code in the aj kit, then I AT THAT POINT in time right click, and "minify" the .js to the "min" version. I have found that if you don't do that, you wind up when building the aj kit that you now have your modified .js files, but the .min.js files HAVE NOT been updated! So, when you run project as debug, it will work, but if you turn on in web config debug=true (remove debug setting), then you find that your aj controls and bits and parts are now using the .min.js, but they are not minified correctly during the build. So, EVEN if you build your project as "release", you wind up without the "min.js" files.

Bottom line: any js files, include the min files BEFORE you re-build the aj toolkit.

I grabbed a nuget package that adds a right click context menu to vs, and thus you can right after making changes to any .js file in the aj kit, then you minimize at developer time.

In this case, you not actually modifying any .js, but replacing, so make sure you replace both the .js, and the .min.js files for this to work if you going to re-build the aj toolkit.

At that point, you can re-build the whole she-bang, and now start to use the new ajaxtoolkit DLL for your project.

Bottom line:

You WILL have to :

A) re-build's the aj toolkit with the newer jQuery version.

or

B) muck around in the project, see if you can remove the existing jQuery references, but that could result in a lot of work, since you have to dig up and see where, when, and how the aj build process includes the jQuery bits and parts - I'm not sure I would go down that road.

In other words, the safe bet is to include the new jQuery.js, jQuery.min.js, and re-build. That would up-date jQuery for you.

Part 2 of these great quest would then to consider if you can remove the jQuery reference(s) in the aj toolkit 100%. So, less risk, less effort, less time is to simple update jQuery.js, jQuery.min.js, and re-build.

I recent updated a site to latest jQuery, but I forgot that site also using the aj toolkit (your post here has informed me that I HAVE MORE work to do here!).

I have to now remember to go and update jQuery in my copy of the aj toolkit.

Either way, you look to have to get/grab a copy of the aj toolkit source code (it's on GitHub), and do your own re-build to control what version of jQuery it going to use.

You could also I suppose as noted, just go and check what version of jQuery their latest build includes.